Unifying Date Format in Tabular Data
When working with data in Pandas, one of the common issues encountered is inconsistent date formats. This may happen when reading from a .xlsx file:
main_t = pd.read_excel(DATA_PATH + "bank.xlsx")

For example, you may have some dates as strings and others as datetime objects, which makes it difficult to perform operations on them. I encountered the following issues:
main_t['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(main_t['Date']).dt.strftime("%y-%m-%d")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: unconverted data remains when parsing with format "%Y-%m-%d"

Further inspect show that fail conversion is due to the inconsistent data format:
main_t['Date'].unique()
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>>> array(['2019-12-31', '2020-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2022-12-31', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 0, 0)], dtype=object)

This inconsistency caused issues when performing any kind of date operations.

Your example seems to work fine. You could try pd.to_datetime(main_t['Date'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime("%y-%m-%d")

To resolve this issue, I wrote a function to unify the date format in the Date column. The goal was to convert all date entries into a standardized string format of yyyy-mm-dd. Here's the function I implemented:
import pandas as pd 
def unify_date_format(df, date_column):
    df[date_column] = pd.to_datetime(df[date_column], errors='coerce')
    df[date_column] = df[date_column].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return df

main_t = unify_date_format(main_t, 'Date')
main_t['Date'].unique()
------------------------------------------------------
>>>array(['2019-12-31', '2020-12-31', '2021-12-31', '2022-12-31'],
      dtype=object)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
